# Why does breaking out of a function affect the array in this way?

Tags: arrays, c, function, file

I have been at work for a replica of the [Oware Abapa](http://www.oware.org/abapa.asp) board game, and have run into an issue. I have a `saveState` function that saves the current state of the game board to a file with the user names, and that all works great, but when that loop ends, my game board is affected, when it should remain just the same.
Below is how my game board is set up, being that `p` is short for pit and `s` is short for score.

```c
void show(int player, t_Pit p[], t_Pit s[], int win) {
    int a = player, o = !a; // 'a'ctive & 'o'pponent

    int x = a ? 0 : 6;
    int y = a ? 6 : 0;
    char *str = win ? "Wins the game\n\n" : "Select pit (1-6)\nSave board state (0): ";
    printf( "\n"
            "----+-----player%d-----+\n"
            "%2d  |%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|\n"
            "----+-----------------+\n"
            "%2d  |%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|\n"
            "----+-----player%d-----+\t"

            "\nPlayer %d %s",
            o,  s[o], p[y+5], p[y+4], p[y+3], p[y+2], p[y+1], p[y+0], // NB: custom indexing
            s[a], p[x+0], p[x+1], p[x+2], p[x+3], p[x+4], p[x+5], a,
            a, str
    );
}
```

Additionally, here's my `saveState` function:

```c
void saveFile(int player, t_Pit p[], t_Pit s[]) {
    char fName[26];
    printf("Input a name for the save file:");
    scanf("%s", &fName);
    FILE *save = fopen(fName, "w");
    if (save == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file for writing");
        return;
    }

    int a = player, o = !a; // 'a'ctive & 'o'pponent

    int x = a ? 0 : 6;
    int y = a ? 6 : 0;

    fprintf(save,
            "%2d\n"
            "%2d %2d %2d %2d %2d %2d\n"
            "%2d\n"
            "%2d %2d %2d %2d %2d %2d\n",
            s[o], p[y+5], p[y+4], p[y+3], p[y+2], p[y+1], p[y+0],
            s[a], p[x+0], p[x+1], p[x+2], p[x+3], p[x+4], p[x+5]);

    fclose(save);
    printf("file '%s' saved.", fName);
}
```

The code in `main()` that manages that function is

```c
int main(void) {
    enum { nPlayer = 2, nOne = 6, nPit = (2*nOne), nSeed = 4, nWin = 25 }; // ease of code

    t_Pit score[ nPlayer ] = { 0 };
    t_Pit pit[ nPit ] = { 0 };
    int counter = 0;
    int counter1 = 0;
    int i;
    int actv = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nPit; ++i) {
        pit[i] = nSeed;
    }

    for ( ; score[0] < nWin && score[1] < nWin; actv = !actv) {
        int from, to;
        while (counter == 0) {
            if (counter1 == 1) {
                if (from == 0) { 
                    saveFile(actv, pit, score);
                    break;
                }
                if (scanf("%d", &from) != 1 || from < 1 || from > 6 || (pit[(from - 1) + fix] <= 1 && temp > 1) || (pit[(from - 1) + fix] == 0 && temp == 1) ) {
                    puts("Out of bounds, select pit (1-6): ");
                } else {
                    counter = 1; 
                }
            }
        }
        counter = 0; 
        counter1 = 0;
        from -= 1; // 0 indexing
        from += fix;
        to = from;

        int nSow = pit[ from ];
        pit[ from ] = 0;

        while (nSow) { //if more than 12 seeds, skip from pit
            if ((to = (to+1) % nPit) != from) {
                ++pit[ to ];
                --nSow;
            }
        }

        while (nSow--) //moving
            pit[ to = (to+1)%nPit ]++;

        // condition true only while in opponent's range of pits
        for ( ; to/nOne != from/nOne; to = (to+(nPit-1))%nPit) // modulo -1
            if (pit[ to ] == 2 || pit[ to ] == 3) {
                score[ actv ] += pit[ to ];
                pit[ to ] = 0;
            } else
                break;
}
```

When I save a file, a play is made from the last pit of the active player, and I'm not quite sure why that is and how I could fix that issue. I assume its got something to do with the `break;` statement but i'm not sure.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us.

Comment: I also recommend you learn how to use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through your code line by line, while monitoring variables and their value, to see what really happens.

Comment: where in your code do you load your saved file?

Comment: `if (counter1 == 1)` -- `counter1` is initialized to 0 and there doesn't seem to be any code that changes its value, so this condition is always false, and so `counter` is never set to 1, and so `while (counter == 0)` is an infinite loop. `from` is uninitialized and may not take a value (if the loop problem were fixed), so `if (from == 0)` has potential UB. There is a stray `~` character at the beginning of the body of the `if` statement wrapped around `scanf()`. This code must not be actual code. Provide a [mcve]: it should be minimally complete, compile, and run to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: To me this question is unclear. You write about "affect the array in this way" but you never secribe what that is.  Further you mention a function `saveStae` but there is no code for that function at all. It's not even called from `main`. Finally, your `main` is an endless loop with no output. Did you post the wrong code?

Comment: `int from, to;` You need to initialize these variables.

Comment: What does ```actv = !actv``` in line ```for( ; score[0] < nWin && score[1] < nWin; actv = !actv ) {``` do, at all? Who's going to change it? Is it ```saveFile``` to change ```actv```?

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh It will toggle the value of `actv` between 0 and 1 for each iteration, presumably for alternating between player 0 and player 1.

Comment: @IanAbbott is right, it's how i alternate the players

Comment: @ramwen0 Sorry, but doing `actv = !actv` inside the for-loop, is just obfuscating the code and make it harder to read and understand. Since you aren't using the initialization expression, and the conditional expression isn't using the variable that you change in the modify statement, it would be much clearer with a `while`-loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you save the game, you do `break` from the `while` loop before reading the value of `from`. Control flows to the body of the outer `for` loop, which proceeds with a bogus uninitialized value of `from`, causing erratic behavior until the next turn.

You should definitely remove this `break` statement.

Note also that the test `if (from == 0)` has undefined behavior in the first iteration because `from` is uninitialized so its value can be anything.  Initialize it to `0` if you want the game to be save systematically.  You could also check the value read from the user and give `0` special semantics such as saving the game.  For this you should move the test after the `scanf()`.

Here is a modified version of the loop:

```
            for (;;) {
                if (scanf("%d", &from) != 1) {
                    // input was not a number
                    int c;
                    printf("invalid input\n");
                    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
                        continue;
                    if (c == EOF)
                        exit(1);
                } else
                if (from == 0) {
                    // special value: save state
                    saveFile(actv, pit, score);
                } else
                if (from < 1 || from > 6
                ||  (pit[(from - 1) + fix] <= 1 && temp > 1)
                ||  (pit[(from - 1) + fix] == 0 && temp == 1)) {
                    puts("Out of bounds, select pit (1-6): ");
                } else {
                    break; 
                }
            }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, how can i make it so that pressing 0 always saves the current game state, without breaking code or getting undeined behaviour? If I put the test after the ```scanf()``` won't that just make it so that its never accessible?

Comment: @ramwen0: I updated the answer for this purpose

Comment: Thank you, should I then remove the while or nest it into the for loop? I'd like to add that inside that while loop there are more game rules, so removing that while would break the existing code as well... @chqrlie

Comment: I have just tested the code, and I got unexpexted behaviour, as I couldn't make a play in the first play of the game and once I tested to save, it wouldn't return to the game right after. Using ```continue;``` does not fix my issue, and I assume that using ```break;``` wont, either.

Comment: Trial and error does not work for this.  You have to stop and reflect on what you want to do and what steps the program should take to implement your purpose.  I don't understand the purpose of the `counter1` behavior and I don't know the game logic of Awele so I cannot check its implementation beyond what I already commented.